# Android Get xml from each class

Tags: android, xml

I need a adapter for getting a UI veiw and putting it to each tab classes.

My target is to put the fixed UI in a xml and i dont want to copy them for each xml. Only i want to get this view from each class. This is the logo part of my application!

Comment: i dont get exactly what you want?  can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

ok... give this a try.... hope this helps

```
LayoutInflater li = this.getLayoutInflater();   
      View v = li.inflate(R.layout.neededxml,null);
      LinearLayout logoView = new LinearLayout(this);
      LinearLayout vgr=(LinearLayotu)li.inflate(R.layout.mainxml,null);
      vgr.addView(logoView);
      vgr.addView(v);
      this.setContentView(vgr);
```